# Add Elements Dynamically With JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, serialization

I would like to add buttons dynamically to my JSON string with PHP and JsonSerializable Interface.

To test, I have a database with a "apps" table who contain "id", "token" and "json" columns.

A View element contains Buttons elements, Buttons elements contain Toto element.

I have a class for each element and I serialize to JSON all class attributes.

I created a little form to add buttons, buttons are appended but not at the same level in JSON.

Here my code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('init.php'); // Database connection

class View implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;
    private $id;
    private $Button;

    function __construct($name, $id, $buttons)
    {

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->Button = array($buttons);
    }

    public function setButton($buttons) { array_push($this->Button, $buttons); }

    public function jsonSerialize() { return (get_object_vars($this)); }
}

class Toto implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() { return (get_object_vars($this)); }
}

class Button implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;
    private $id;
    private $Element;

    function __construct($name, $id)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->Element = new Toto('Titi');
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() { return (get_object_vars($this)); }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    $q = $mysqli->query('
         SELECT json
         FROM apps
         WHERE token = "abc"');
    if ($q->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        $d = $q->fetch_object();
        $result = $d->json;
        var_dump(json_decode($result)->Button);
    }
    else
        $result = null;
    if (isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        if ($q->num_rows >= 1)
        {
            $view = new View('Home', 1, json_decode($result)->Button);
            $view->setButton(new Button($_POST['name'], 12));
            $newJSON = json_encode($view, (JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

            $mysqli->query('
            UPDATE apps
            SET token = "abc",
                json = "' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($newJSON) . '"
            WHERE token = "abc"');
        }
        else
        {
            $view = new View('Home', 1, new Button($_POST['name'], 12));
            $newJSON = json_encode($view, (JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

            $mysqli->query('
            INSERT INTO apps
            SET token = "abc",
                json = "' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($newJSON) . '"');
        }

        header('Location: archi.php');
        exit;
    }
    ?>
    <pre><?php print_r($result); ?></pre>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <button type="submit" name="add">Add button</button>
</form>
```

Here my currently output with three buttons added:

```
{
"name": "Home",
"id": 1,
"Button": [
    [
        [
            {
                "name": "Send",
                "id": 12,
                "Element": {
                    "name": "Titi"
                }
            }
        ],
        {
            "name": "Cancel",
            "id": 12,
            "Element": {
                "name": "Titi"
            }
        }
    ],
    {
        "name": "Invite",
        "id": 12,
        "Element": {
            "name": "Titi"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I would like this result:

```
{
"name": "Home",
"id": 1,
"Button": [
    {
        "name": "Send",
        "id": 12,
        "Element": {
            "name": "Titi"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Cancel",
        "id": 12,
        "Element": {
            "name": "Titi"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Invite",
        "id": 12,
        "Element": {
            "name": "Titi"
        }
    }
]
}
```

How can I arrived to this result ? I'm stuck.

Mickey42.

Comment: Looks like the `$buttons` you're passing in is an array of buttons? If so, then array_push() will push that entire array onto the main $Buttons array as a single element. It's not a "merge" where your X-element $Buttons array suddenly gains N new buttons. It'll gain +1 buttons, where that +1 is a sub-array of however many other buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes I see, yes I give array of buttons but how can I do a "merge" at the the same Buttons level ?

Comment: `foreach($new_buttons_array as $newbutton) { array_push($this->Buttons, $newbutton); }`, or something like [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already tried these methods but I do not see how implement that in my code to arrive at the good result.